# Automation test for SOAP services?

Tags: web-services, testing, jenkins, soap, automation

In our architecture we have mule application with a list of webservices, we use jenkins for continuos integration/deployment.
No automation test at all at the moment, only few unit tests.

I was thinking to add a step after each deploy to test all webservices, something like:

- input: url and request body
- output: check the response code, than the response body

my questions are:

1. Should I use a framework to integrate in our code?
2. Is a simple file with the list of the webservices and a file for each
   response/request a good idea to do that?
3. which tool do you advise me?soapui?Can I do everything I need with the free version one?
4. should the test be ran after each deploy?

Any advise or thoughts on that?

**UPDATE**:
at the moment I created a file in the sourcecode with the list of all endpoints. We are integrating it in jenkins after every deploy. We only check the return code 200 for now.

Thanks

Comment: ok, I will add what I have tried so far.

Comment: > I was thinking to add
Why this? it could be better to stop and plan on what to add first

Comment: well, why? to add a real end to end testing after a real deployment.